# Language/Region selection i18n drupal 7

Tags: i18n-l10n

I would like to implement a Region selector in a Drupal 7 website. Not the default i18n where you have 1 language for multiple countries but English content for the USA and different English content for the UK.

For configuration I would like to select the applicable regions on my node (maybe with taxonomy items?) so when the content is the same for multiple region's we don't need to duplicate it in all region's/languages.

Is there a solid solution for my needs?

THANKS!

Answer (score 1):

To get a different content and/or interface for the USA and UK, go to *admin/config/regional/language/add* :

In predefined language, select **English, british**. This will add a new "english British" language with *en-gb* prefix, while default english has *en* prefix, and will import related .po files.

If you have only en-US and en-GB in your project, when the content is the same for both, simply set it as *Language neutral*  in the content node submission.

Maybe you already know the great article series [Drupal 7's new multilingual systems compilation](http://hojtsy.hu/multilingual-drupal7). It is a valuable source to get a complete overview of Drupal 7 multilingual setup.